# converting gridview to itextsharp table and generating pdf using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview, itext

here i am trying to convert GridView to PDF, when converting PDF not getting the GridView column width in PDF.So i used another method to generate PDF (i.e) created itextsharp table from GridView .Here i got column width size which i gave in GridView column ItemStyle-Width.But i have done grouped column in that GridView so i am not getting the full GridView with same column width in PDF.can anyone please help me .

here is the source:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     onsorting="GridView1_Sorting">
     <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4F81BD" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#ffffff" HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Size="12px"/>
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#D3DFEE" />
    <RowStyle />
    <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category"
            SortExpression="Category" ItemStyle-Width="100px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Partno" HeaderText="Partno" 
             ItemStyle-Width="100px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Productname" HeaderText="Productname" 
             ItemStyle-Width="300px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Brand" HeaderText="Brand" 
            ItemStyle-Width="100px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Qty" HeaderText="Qty" 
             ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Unitprice" HeaderText="Unitprice" 
             ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Totalprice" HeaderText="Totalprice" 
             ItemStyle-Width="50px"/>
    </Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

here is the grouped gridview:

[image]

here is the code to convert gridview to itextsharp table and generating PDF:

```
//Create a table
iTextSharp.text.Table table = new iTextSharp.text.Table(GridView1.Columns.Count);
table.Cellpadding = 5;
//Set the column widths
int[] widths = new int[GridView1.Columns.Count];
for (int x = 0; x < GridView1.Columns.Count; x++)
{
    widths[x] = (int)GridView1.Columns[x].ItemStyle.Width.Value;
    string cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[x].Text);
    iTextSharp.text.Cell cell = new iTextSharp.text.Cell(cellText);
    cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#008000"));
    table.AddCell(cell);
}

table.SetWidths(widths);
//Transfer rows from GridView to table

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (GridView1.Rows[i].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < GridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            string cellText = Page.Server.HtmlDecode(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text);
            iTextSharp.text.Cell cell = new iTextSharp.text.Cell(cellText);

            //Set Color of Alternating row
            if (i % 2 != 0)
            {
                cell.BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.Color(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#C2D69B"));
            }

            table.AddCell(cell);
        }
    }
}

//Create the PDF Document

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
pdfDoc.Add(table);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" +
                               "filename=GridViewExport.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

here is the PDF:

[image]

i want exact gridview with same column width in PDF.

Answer (score 2):

The `PdfPTable` uses relative widths by default. When you say `table.SetWidths(widths)` iText sums up `widths` and divides each individual width by that sum to get a percentage. So `1, 2, 3` is the same as `10, 20, 30` and even `2, 4, 6`. You want to use `SetTotalWidth(widths)` along with setting `LockedWidth = true` the force absolute widths.

```
table.SetTotalWidth(widths);
table.LockedWidth = true;
```

However, doing this is declaring that you are now aware of and in control of the table's horizontal layout. If you overflow the page horizontally you will not getting any wrapping and things will just cut off. You are also declaring that margin space is acceptable to run into if needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I got column width as i mentioned in gridview but my problem is not showing full gridview in pdf (i.e) see grouped gridview image there is totally 8 row but i got only 5 row in pdf(pdf image).

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the issue:

```
GridView1.AllowPaging = False
```